# math - how to properly use MDAS rule in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, math

i'm getting the net value of a query. So far here is my problem. Whereas the `Cost` `EUL` `UL` is the only column while `NetValue` is a query only opened upon the computation.

```
Cost   EUL   UL   NetValue
9000   5     1    7380 // this is what I want to be displayed
```

My formula is like this *in programming*

```
temp=cost-(.10*cost);
temp2=temp/EUL;
temp3=temp2*UL;
temp4=temp3-cost
```

so far here is my query

```
Cost*.10/eul*n_asset_ul //which will be the new column NetValue
```

and the output of my query is

```
Cost   EUL   UL   NetValue
9000   5     1    180
```

Can somebody help?
EDIT: Answers will sometime/always be negative. So i also needed it to be absolute value

Comment: Your query comes nowhere close to the code you included. You're doing only a very small part of the calculation; for instance, you missed half of the calculation done in the first line of code). Read the code again more carefully.

Comment: Sir, the code is for understanding only. That is what I want to achieve in c# way.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the code is there for; did you **read** the words I wrote? I pointed out **very clearly** where the problem is located and what it is - all you need to do is **read what I wrote**, specifically the **second sentence**.

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite understand what you said in the second sentence. English isn't my first language

Comment: I said **you missed HALF OF THE CALCULATION you showed in your first line of code**. Your SQL version is only doing HALF OF THE CALCULATION that `temp=cost-(.10*cost);` is doing. What part of `cost*.10` is not the same as `cost - (.10*cost)` are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: Yes sorry I'm having trouble understanding. And that is what I want from my question. To have the c# code translated into SQL query. If you could, please help. :)

Comment: How can you NOT understand `cost*.10` is not the same as `cost-(.10*cost)`? It seems you need to find a basic math class.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the `temp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the NetValue is equal to cost-(.10*cost))/EUL*UL?

It is a sample:

```
SELECT (Cost-(0.1*Cost))/EUL*UL AS NetValue1 --you r formula
       ,Cost-((Cost-(0.1*Cost))/EUL*UL) AS NetValue2
       ,Cost*(1.0-(0.9/EUL*UL)) AS NetValue3
FROM (VALUES( 9000,5,1)) t(Cost,EUL,UL)
```

```
NetValue1          NetValue2           NetValue3
--------------     ---------------     ---------------------------------------
1620.000000000000   7380.000000000000  7380.000000000000
```

Comment: Hello, as for your first sentence. I forgot to add something in my code and seems like you figured it out.

Comment: I just don't understand where in part of your `NetValue2` makes the output a positive?

Comment: @WTFZane Actually I don‘t know which is right formula for you, I just guessed the formula per the result value.